# Mouse suddenly broken in KDE 12.04, Gnome 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.04, works in Xfce

Tags: xorg

I recently did `apt-get upgrade` and hibernated my computer some hours later. When I started it again, the mouse was broken. Just as if it was unplugged (but it was not). I rebooted the computer and the mouse started to work again, kind of:

- In Kubuntu 12.04: I can left click only the Kubuntu menu bar, but not windows and applications. It's as if the left clicks don't happen at all, when I click windows and applications. *Or* some times I can click windows and applications, but not the Kubuntu menu bar.
- In Ubuntu 12.04 Unity and Gnome: I can click everything, but every 5 seconds a spurious left click happens. As if someone sits next to me and clicks the left mouse button every 5 seconds.

However, the mouse works fine in Ubuntu's main login dialog, and in the Xfce window manager. So apparently the mouse is okay? (I'm using Xfce right now.)

I feel totally at lost as to why the above-mentioned things happen! What might be wrong? What types of problems might cause issues like these? What can I do to fix the mouse issues?

The computer is a desktop not a laptop. Here's the output from `lsusb`:

```
20:16:59 4 ~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
...
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 09da:0006 A4 Tech Co., Ltd Optical Mouse WOP-35 / Trust 450L Optical Mouse
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05f3:0081 PI Engineering, Inc. Kinesis Integrated Hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 05f3:0007 PI Engineering, Inc. Kinesis Advantage PRO MPC/USB Keyboard
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a USB > PS2 adapter to connect your mouse to your PC. 
or
Use a different mouse.

It looks like this was a bug in 9.04 for your specific mouse and may not have been resolved: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/364651 using the PS2 port was a work around mentioned.

Using a different mouse will also help determine if the issue is specific to the mouse or just a general issue with all mice you attach to your system.

If your are using a USB hub there could also be issues with how it is operating. I have not had good luck with powered USB hubs, so if you are using a powered hub you can try disconnecting the power (as long as you are not running a hard disk off of it the 500ma that it pulls form the port on the computer should be sufficient mice and keyboards are going to pull about 100ma each)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting testing with a different mouse or a PS2 adapter. Perhaps I ought to buy a PS2 mouse tomorrow then, it's probably a good idea to have 2 mice anyway. — I don't use any USB hub. — I didn't find any mentioning of my mouse version in the bug report, why do you think the bug report was related to my specific mouse?

Comment: I think almost any other USB mouse is going to work well, so you may not want to get PS2 mouse that will not work with many modern laptops.  The bug report has the same ID in it as your lsusb output.

Comment: Today I bought a USB mouse that included a USB to PS2 adapter. My old mouse works now when I use the adapter. And the new USB mouse also works it seems. Thanks! (So now I have 2 mice.)